# Rails color and colors options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-admin

I've got an interesting problem, interesting as in "***is kind of pissing me off*** ".  I am admittedly a Rails noob so this could be very naive.  I'm trying to hand-code an ecommerce site, in which I have a color model:

```
class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product, foreign_key: 'product_id'
end
```

and this in my product model:

```
  has_many :colors, foreign_key: 'product_id'
```

And it gets interesting here- when I go to add or edit a product in /admin, (railsadmin), I have a "color" option, where I am only able to give one color to the product, and then further down, a "colors" option! (Where I am able to give multiple colors).

In my products listing, when I show this for the color drop down:

```
<%= f.select(:color, options_for_select([product.color])) %>
```

I get a nice listing of the ONE color option, and it actually spells out this color.

When I add an "s" and make the above code "[product.colors]", they all lose their dropdown options except for whichever one has had the colors edited most recently, and this one will show something like:

```
#<Color:0x0000010235cf48>
```

As a sole option in that dropdown.  I would love this to be clarified and sorted out.  Of course, what I am looking for is for the admin to be able to simply add/edit colors, kill whichever of the two color/colors options is dead confusing weight in admin, and for the added colors to show in that particular product's dropdown.

Please let me know if there is any more relevant code I can add.  Thanks all.

Comment: Hm, product should not have `color` method if it `has_many :colors`. Are you sure you're not defining `color` elsewhere on project?

Comment: Forgive me if the above code is just sample code and doesn't resemble your actual models but shouldn't the association between product and color be a many-to-many? Would be a waste to have to go through and fix the problem and find out that the design was wrong in the first place.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev is there any chance this issue is strictly within railsadmin? What should my product color/colors method look like?

Comment: @Saifis thanks for the answer.  A many to many association did not fix the issue.